# How do I save date and time and then sort them from new to old in datagridview, I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, windows

In Visual Studio I have:

```
    'Label15.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/M/yyyy(dddd)   hh:mm:ss:tt")

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label15.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/M/yyyy(dddd)   hh:mm:ss:tt")
    Label16.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("    hh:mm:ss tt    ")
End Sub
```

In sql server currently I'm using a nvarchar data type, what data type should I use?

what im trying to do is make a datagrid view to automatically show new to old records

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime datatype in sql server

Comment: okay and whats next I proceed to   command.Parameters.Add("@datetime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Label15.Text

Comment: Sorry. i am datawarehouse developer..I don't know about application coding.